# React Native Detox e2e tests, attempting .scroll on scroll view triggers error performing click after 3 attempts

Tags: android, react-native, detox

I did not know wether to set this up as an issue or to ask here, this has only been tested in android, I have scrollview in a Screen inside a nested stacknavigator (various scrollviews on stack, only one visible), and I'm trying to scroll down and up, whereas it throws the next error

```
Error: Error: Error performing `click(after 3 attempts)` on view `with tag value: is "stepstep_content_scrollable"
```

This is the code

```
it("Should scroll softly", async () => {
        await element(by.id('step_content_scrollable')).scroll(50,'down')
        await element(by.id('step_content_scrollable')).scroll(50,'up')
    })
```

I tried getting it by tag and.atIndex(), also fails, tried swipe and scrollTo, and both fail as well, swipe just fails saying swipe couldn't be done

I'd appreciate any support